# Mount SMB share from a server with a space in its name

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, mount, smb

I'm trying to mount an SMB share on the terminal. I'm able do to that, if the server has no space in its name using this command:

```
$ mount -t smbfs //user:password@server/resource /Volumes/resource
```

However in my case the server name has a space and I can't figure out how to properly pass such a name.

I tried using double or single quotes:

```
$ mount -t smbfs "//user:password@ser ver/resource" /Volumes/resource
mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument
```

I tried escaping the space:

```
$ mount -t smbfs //user:password@ser\ ver/resource /Volumes/resource
mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument
```

I also tried using `%20`, `\x20` and `\040`, but I get an error:

```
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host
```

I know I could use the IP address or rename the server, but that would be a workaround and not a solution and I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: can you add it in your `fstab`?

Comment: How did you end up with a hostname with a space in it? As far as I understand this is not possible.

Comment: @themel It's an AirPort Extreme with a HDD attached to it. When setting it up using the AirPort Utility, it didn't complain about the space in its name. Finder is also able to connect to the HDD, even with the space.

Comment: Thank you for how to connect to samba, but please do not write the password to the bash, it will be save in your file history in clear.

Comment: The `%20` worked for me on macOS zsh, but it was in the resource name, not the server name. `mount -t smbfs //me:password@NAS/My%20Backups ~/My\ Backups`. Strange.

Comment: See answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command#answer-27027493), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command#answer-37179333)

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you combine quotes and escape:

```
mount -t smbfs "//user:password@ser\ ver/resource" /Volumes/resource
```

That reportedly worked for someone when [mounting an smbfs volume with a space in the username](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/mount-t-smbfs-username-in-with-space-not-accepted-73557/).