# Escape special characters in mount command

Tags: macos, bash, escaping, mount, smb

I am trying to mount a windows shared folder on Mac OSX Mavericks. A simplistic user name and password worked fine

`mount -t smbfs //user2:password2@server1.mydomain.com/myproject ~/localmap`

On trying out the more valid user name and password I am getting errors that parsing URL failed.
The details are 
Username: mydomain\user1
Password: A%b$c@d!e#f

The command tried is

`mount -t smbfs //mydomain\user1:A%b\$c\@d\!e#f@server1.mydomain.com/myproject ~/localmap`

Based on what I found, $ and ! needs to be escaped. Need help on how to escape the special characters. Incidentally, using only the username without the domain seems to work in the first case

Comment: I see you have escapes (`\`) in the command you tried.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Here is the error message
`mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single quotes escape shell meta-characters, [a semi-colon should separate the domain controller from the credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html), and can use `%40` to represent an `@` in the password:

```
mount -t smbfs '//mydomain;user1:A%b$c%40d!e#f@server1.mydomain.com/myproject' ~/localmap
```

Comment: The single quote and the semi colon are fine but the special characters in the password are still giving the same error message.

Comment: I suspect it is the @ symbol since it is used to separate the password from the server name

Comment: Yeah, yikes.  Made an edit, give that a whirl.  The next level of fix is not pretty....

Answer (score 8):

Just encode your special characters.

```
@ -> %40
$ -> %24
! -> %21
```

Others characters can be found here:
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

e.g.

```
username="someone", password="passw@rd"
```

Then this should work for you:

```
mount -t smbfs //someone:passw%40rd@server/path /Volumes/path
```

Comment: this is what worked for me: mount -t smbfs //user:passw\@rd@server/path /volume/path

Answer (score 3):

Use `\` to escape special symbols
if you want to convert some special symbols you can write additional string, where $1 - is parameter you provide for converting

```
user1=$(sed -e "s/+/%2B/g;s/@/%40/g;s/_/%5F/g" <<< "$1")
```

and then you can use `" "` and call your converted variable like this `$user1`

Answer (score 2):

Might be handy to use nodejs to encode the url stuff:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(encodeURIComponent("A%b$c@d!e#f"))'
A%25b%24c%40d!e%23f
```

Decode to go the other way:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(decodeURIComponent("A%25b%24c%40d!e%23f"))'
A%b$c@d!e#f
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see https://serverfault.com/questions/309429/mount-cifs-credentials-file-has-special-character, the first answer there worked for me. Basically, you create a file with the credentials and then specify that file instead of your username and password.

Comment: Your "answer" is related to `cifs` and not `mount_smbfs` which doesn't support the credentials file.