# Terminal: how to escape @ email sign in Samba username

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

We have a shared Samba that uses default Windows username with email in it. How do you escape @ to make the command work?

```
mount volume "smb://john@gmail.com:password@desktop-PC/X"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `%40` instead of `@` in the username.

```sh
mount volume 'smb://john%40gmail.com:password@desktop-PC/X'
```

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command).

Comment: thank you b3z. I did a search but did not see that topic. I did your command but it still says that host gmail.com is not reachable. So it doesn't escape it now.

Comment: Did you try using the -o flag? https://amalgjose.com/2020/05/22/how-to-use-password-with-special-character-in-mount-command-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the game, but this worked for me, and maybe it is useful for other.

On your Windows computer, find out what the actual username is that Windows is using. Go to **Computer Management** -> **Local Users and Groups** -> **Users**.  (assuming Windows 10 or 11)

You’ll see all accounts listed here. On my Windows machine I login with my Microsoft account email address, but internally it actually only shows my first name. Use this name and try again (column “Name”).